# SQL Server - VIEWS - keep track of last altered time and the user that altered it

Tags: sql-server, view

I would like to create a custom table where I should store the last altered date of a `VIEW` and the `SYSTEM_USER` that altered it.

The last updated date of the `VIEW` I can retrieve it using this query:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'v'
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

However, the above table does not keep information about the user that had altered the view.

Is there any way to do this in SQL? `INSTEAD OF` triggers is not a solution.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to use Version Control to manage your databases, then you can see a lot more than just who altered a view and when. You can see what the changes were, and assuming they are using the software properly why they made the change, what feature it was part of etc. If this is not possible Aaron Betrand describes a pretty good solution using database triggers in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/), although not sure if this is what you mean by "`INSTEAD OF` triggers is not a solution"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: @GarethD - since `INSTEAD OF` can be used with `UPDATE`, `INSERT` etc. and no one will ever do an update on this view nor insert.

Comment: You wouldn't be looking at an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, as those are related to DML triggers. If you need to store such information it would be in a DDL trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Object auditing is available in Enterprise Edition.

Cheaper options - I think there are a few third party products out there that can also do it.

Short of the above, I don't believe there's a way. Sorry.